# Call Mongodb stored function from PHP7

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, laravel, function

Below is my mongodb function that is stored in Mongodb.

`db.system.js.save(
      {
       _id: "echoFunction",
       value : function(x) { return x; }
     }
   )`

I can call this function in mongo using below query :

`db.loadServerScripts();
     echoFunction(3);`

Now i want to call this function from PHP 7. and also help with laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code snippet from laravel to execute your mongoDB function.

`$cursor = DB::connection('mongodb')->command(array('eval' => 'echoFunction("4")'));
 $data = $cursor->toArray();
 dd($data);`

Try and let me know if it works.

Comment: How do you put this into  an update query for updating a record based on the output of the function?