# How to Call MongoDB Stored Function from Laravel.(Mongo Version 4.2.2)

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I have tried below one,but it is not working for  `Mongo 4.2.2`  Version.Please help me to resolve this.

[Call Mongodb stored function from PHP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088817/call-mongodb-stored-function-from-php7)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Mongodb stored function from PHP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088817/call-mongodb-stored-function-from-php7)

Comment: If you have a new question, please write a complete question. Otherwise this is a duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: @D.SM It is not working for `Mongo 4.2.2`